# how to hide only markers in route me

Tags: route-me

i want to show /hide markers on route me map initialised for osm.
but using command [marker manager hideAllMarkers]; hides not only markers on map but also routes or anything added to marker manager.How to hide only markers and keep other things in marker manager intact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well solved it by adding two methods in RMMarker class

```
-(void)showMarker{
    [self setHidden:NO];
 }

-(void)hideMarker{
    [self setHidden:YES];
}

And finally iterate through marker manager
NSArray* markers = markerManager.markers;

        for(RMMarker *mk in markers)
        {
            if ([mk isKindOfClass:[RMMarker class]]&&[mk.accessibilityLabel isEqual:@"xyz"])
            {
                [mk showMarker];
            }
        }
```

similarly u can do the same for RMPath class